# If statement syntax error?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

```
try:
    f = int(factor)
    if (factor == 0):
        print("No factors present to derive");
    elif (factor != int):
        print ("Numbers only please!");
    elif (factor >> 4):
        print("Four maximum factors!");
    else:
        f = int(factor);
if f == 1:
    coefficientone = raw_input("What is the coefficient on the first term?")
        try:
        coef1 = int(coefficientone)
        if (coef1 == 0):
            print "No coefficient present, please re-enter polynomial"
        elif (coef1 != int)
            print "Numbers only please!"
        else:
            coef1 = int(coefficientone)
```

This returns a syntax error on the if f == 1: line. Please help! From what I have read on this site and most other sites that line looks to be correct. I would appreciate any help on any other portion of the code, too, for this is my first time working with python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the "except" block to match the "try" block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to add a `try` block, you have to have a matching `except`, to handle the exception you're catching.

If you don't know why you're adding the `try` block, it's best to simply *remove it*, as to not mask potential errors. It's best to only `except` specific error types.

Here's the fixed code. The changes are noted with comments.

```
try:
    f = int(factor)
    if (factor == 0):
        print("No factors present to derive");
    elif (factor != int):
        print ("Numbers only please!");
    elif (factor >> 4):
        print("Four maximum factors!");
    else:
        f = int(factor);
except Exception as e:                            # Add this
    print 'ERROR: {0}'.format(e)                  #

if f == 1:
    coefficientone = raw_input("What is the coefficient on the first term?")
    try:                                          # Un-indent this
        coef1 = int(coefficientone)
        if (coef1 == 0):
            print "No coefficient present, please re-enter polynomial"
        elif (coef1 != int)
            print "Numbers only please!"
        else:
            coef1 = int(coefficientone)
    except Exception as e:                        # Add this
        print 'ERROR: {0}'.format(e)              #
```

Finally, it seems like you're planning on asking the user for as many coefficients as he specifies. For this, you'll probably want to consider using a `for` loop to handle the input, and a `list` to store the values. I'll leave the implementation details up to you. There are plenty of resources out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
#an error that I am seeing is that factor != int should be:
elif type(factor) != int:
#and adding to the try I think that you will also need a except ValueError:
```

Comment: While this is true, it's not breaking his code. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that we can put comments. I am new to stackoverflow